# Clean Multi X Server Setup

Tags: linux, io, x-server, kodi

I want to spawn a second X Server for my TV and use a Media Station software like xbmc over it. Is it best practice to manage multi x instances from xinit or is there another/better way?
Apart from that, it would be nice to have separate keyboard/mouse setups for each X server, is this possible?

regards

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: a Radeon HD 7770

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Xinerama. If you are using ghe proprietary ATI drivers, which is probably a good idea, you can set this up using `aticonfig`. Also see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo) for some example xorg.conf files.

Although I have never tried this myself, you should be able to have different keyboard and mouse sections in your xorg.conf and assign a diferent setup to each X server.